# WARNING: no suitable primes in /etc/ssh/primes message after changing user's password

Tags: ssh, macos, .net

So I am using a SSH.Net library to do some stuff from my .Net application to trigger stuff on a remote Mac OS device.
After I changed user's password I managed to break the functionality somehow and system.log shows me the following message:

```
 WARNING: no suitable primes in /etc/ssh/primes
```

The library itself gives me this message:

```
An exception of type 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException' occurred in Renci.SshNet.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication.
```

SSHD debug gives me this message:

```
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 6 out 6 newsock 6 pipe -1 sock 9
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 5, 5
Connection from 172.16.115.19 port 44670 on 192.168.202.110 port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version Renci.SshNet.SshClient.0.0.1
debug1: no match: Renci.SshNet.SshClient.0.0.1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 569
debug1: list_hostkey_types:  [preauth]
No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 569
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the keys that have changed after the password was changed, but I am not 100% sure here.

Comment: I recommend trying to connect with the normal command-line SSH client (with `-v` if that helps, too). That will at least tell you if it's a problem on the server or something odd that you're doing with your client library.

Comment: That actually works without any issue.. I am able to connect with Kitty with no problem

Comment: In that case, server-side debug logs will come in handy. Run `sshd -d -d -P 2222` as root on the server and then connect to port 2222 from the client. Edit those logs into your question.

Comment: It tells me: sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path

Comment: Yeah, so you should do what it says: use an absolute path. `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -P 2222` or wherever your `sshd` is.

Comment: Posting the full log in the original question

Comment: Well, you could have formatted it decently instead of posting one giant line-wrapped blob, but it seems to be you've got your answer in there: `No supported key exchange algorithms`. Although that error makes me wonder whether `sshd` is really running as root...

Comment: So I basically need to renew the SSH keys?

Comment: What are you talking about??

Answer (score 0):

> I am guessing this has something to do with the keys that have changed after the password was changed, but I am not 100% sure here.

No.

```
No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
```

talks about **key exchange algorithms**. The log is not complete (`-ddd` will tell you more) and from older version that is not much verbose in this level. But I can guess your server does not support anymore the method offered by your `SSH.Net` library.

I would go for upgrading the library in the first place. The second possibility is to allow legacy Kex algorithms on server, such as:

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1

in your `sshd_config` (basically adding `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` and `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` which are not considered as a safe these days!).